# What do I need to know to build stone steps?

Tags: hard-landscape

- Can I do this safely and economically by myself?
- What skills do I need to build using natural stone?
- What's better about doing it yourself? Why wouldn't I hire a contractor?
- What do I need to know before I start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can build your own steps using flagstone, some simple tools and your  planning and labour.**

While this is not a beginner project, with preparation you can have the satisfaction of doing a great safe job that a contractor would charge thousands of dollars for.  Be prepared to invest some time in thinking before you start digging.  Here are some of the issues to consider:

- what kind of soil do you have: clay, sand, soil or whatever the builder left behind? Compacted clay soil can support stone laid directly on top. Sandy soil offers very little frost heave and no support for stone.
- measurements: the length and height, width of the area
- transition areas, top, bottom sides: how will you deal with these areas?
- what is the amount of rainfall and frost heaving in your area?
- how will you dispose of the soil? I needed a 40 yard dump bin.
- what kind of traffic: just foot traffic, lawnmowers?, wheelbarrows? skiers?
- what kind of style: formal characterized by a symmetric design, more straight lines or informal, rustic?
- many areas have bylaws regarding steps and they have them for safety reasons. Investigate whether you need handrails and other best practices.
- Utilities: gas, phone, cable.  Call before you dig and get them marked.

See related material here

- [Tools you need](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4334/what-tools-do-i-need-to-build-stone-steps)
- [Working safely](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/how-do-i-work-safely-with-stone)
- [Step by step with pictures and diagrams](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/building-natural-stone-steps)
- [A finished project and more tips](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4342/what-problems-should-i-expect-to-encounter-when-building-stone-steps)

Here is a "before" picture of the slope I had to deal with

[image: October 2007]

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to add that you need to consult your local planning laws.

For our local council they only allow a certain amount of cutting and filling before you need to apply.

There is also limits on the size of retaining walls.